# MongoDB. Missing ] in property name

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections, insert, database

Hi I have the book collection in which I want to insert an array of documents :

```
> db.book.insert({[ {x:null},{y:true},{a:3.23},{b:'abc'},
  {c:new Date()},{d:[1,2,3]}, {f:1} ]})
```

It gives me this error :

```
2016-03-06T00:53:58.893+0300 E QUERY    
[thread1] **SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name @(shell):1:27**
```

I **can't see the missing ']'**, what is my fault?

I want to add 7 documents at the same time.

I need to do include all the documents in an array, right? **.insert({[ ... ]})**

as you see document **'d'** is also an array.

Comment: It would be `db.book.insert([{ "x": null },{ "y": true }])`. You placed the square brackets `[]` "inside" the curly brackets `{}`. It's meant to be "outside" to be a "list"

Comment: You are right! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Solved by removing the **'{}'** in the **'()'** :

Final result:

```
db.book.insert([ {x:null},{y:true},{a:3.23},{b:'abc'},
{c:new Date()},{d:[1,2,3]}, {f:1} ])
```